# How to rip dvd and arrange files

Tags: dvd, encoding, ripping, authoring

I'm ripping a dvd with dvd shrink. There are lots of anime episodes on it. And when I open those .vob files it seems that the episodes are not arranged in one .vob file. Because 1 .vob file has multiple episodes but they are not arranged as ep 1, ep 2, ep 3, etc. Is it possible to edit those files so that the episodes would be arranged

Comment: are you trying to "arrange" these to burn as a new DVD, or to encode them as AVI/MKV/WMV/MP4 files?  what you are asking is very unclear.

Answer (score 2):

There are different alternatives to achieve what you want to do. [This guide](http://www.videohelp.com/forum/archive/how-to-convert-dvd-tv-episodes-to-avi-xvid-or-mp4-h264-with-subtitles-t357932.html) explains how to convert DVD episodes to AVI XviD or MP4 H264 with subtitles. It includes required tools (you have freeware option), preparation and explanation with screenies of the process.

As an alternative, [this guide](http://download.videohelp.com/cheekie_moonkie/guides/ddtool.html) also tells about how to easily convert a DVD with episodes to multiple DivX/XviD files.

I hope this helps.